# HTML: I'm trying to use then integrate a form template, but when I hit submit it just goes to the PHP file. Help fixing this?

Tags: php, html, forms

**Form template origin**: http://www.html-form-guide.com/contact-form/php-email-contact-form.html

**HTML form page**:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> 
<html>
<head>
    <title>Contact us</title>
<!-- define some style elements-->
<style>
h1
{
    font-family : Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size : 16px;
    font-weight : bold;
}
label,a 
{
    font-family : Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size : 12px; 
}

</style>    
<!-- a helper script for vaidating the form-->
<script language="JavaScript" src="scripts/gen_validatorv31.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head> 
</head>

<body>
<h1>Contact us</h1>
<form method="POST" name="contactform" action="contact-form-handler.php"> 
<p>
<label for='name'>Your Name:</label> <br>
<input type="text" name="name">
</p>
<p>
<label for='email'>Email Address:</label> <br>
<input type="text" name="email"> <br>
</p>
<p>
<label for='message'>Message:</label> <br>
<textarea name="message"></textarea>
</p>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"><br>
</form>

<script language="JavaScript">
// Code for validating the form
// Visit http://www.javascript-coder.com/html-form/javascript-form-validation.phtml
// for details
var frmvalidator  = new Validator("contactform");
frmvalidator.addValidation("name","req","Please provide your name"); 
frmvalidator.addValidation("email","req","Please provide your email"); 
frmvalidator.addValidation("email","email","Please enter a valid email address"); 
</script>
<!--
Sample code from:
http://www.html-form-guide.com/contact-form/php-email-contact-form.html
-->


</body>
</html>
```

**PHP script**:

```
<?php 
$errors = '';
$myemail = 'yourname@website.com';//<-----Put Your email address here.
if(empty($_POST['name'])  || 
   empty($_POST['email']) || 
   empty($_POST['message']))
{
    $errors .= "\n Error: all fields are required";
}

$name = $_POST['name']; 
$email_address = $_POST['email']; 
$message = $_POST['message']; 

if (!preg_match(
"/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/i", 
$email_address))
{
    $errors .= "\n Error: Invalid email address";
}

if( empty($errors))
{
    $to = $myemail; 
    $email_subject = "Contact form submission: $name";
    $email_body = "You have received a new message. ".
    " Here are the details:\n Name: $name \n Email: $email_address \n Message \n $message"; 

    $headers = "From: $myemail\n"; 
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";

    mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
    //redirect to the 'thank you' page
    header('Location: contact-form-thank-you.html');
} 
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> 
<html>
<head>
    <title>Contact form handler</title>
</head>

<body>
<!-- This page is displayed only if there is some error -->
<?php
echo nl2br($errors);
?>


</body>
</html>
```

**Details**:
When I type in some details then click submit, I am redirected to the PHP script in my browser. Can I please have some guidance as I have researched quite a bit and don't really know much PHP.
I hope that's enough details!

Comment: are you running this pages using a web server?

Comment: According to your HTML you are calling contact-form-handler.php.  You have named your PHP page this correct?

Comment: khakiout - Testing locally. Should I try uploading then do it again?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want your form to be redirect on php page than you need to use ajax to submit your form and then get response from php file. Give your form an id (suppose that for id is  contactform)

// Jquery code

```
    <script>
    $("#contactform").submit(function(event){
       event.preventDefault();
       $.ajax({
       method: "POST",
       url: "contact-form-handler.php",
      data: { name: $("#name"), email: $("#email"),message: $("#message") },
    success: function(response){
          alter(response.data);
    }

       })
    })

    </script>
```

// PHP- CODE

```
$errors = '';
$myemail = 'yourname@website.com';//<-----Put Your email address here.
if(empty($_POST['name'])  || 
   empty($_POST['email']) || 
   empty($_POST['message']))
{
    $errors .= "\n Error: all fields are required";
}

$name = $_POST['name']; 
$email_address = $_POST['email']; 
$message = $_POST['message']; 

if (!preg_match(
"/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/i", 
$email_address))
{
    $errors .= "\n Error: Invalid email address";
}

if( empty($errors))
{
    $to = $myemail; 
    $email_subject = "Contact form submission: $name";
    $email_body = "You have received a new message. ".
    " Here are the details:\n Name: $name \n Email: $email_address \n Message \n $message"; 

    $headers = "From: $myemail\n"; 
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";

    mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
    //Set an success message, here i have used the variable name as error you can change it as per requirment.

    $error = 'Mail Sent successfully !!';
} 
$data['error'] = $error;
echo json_encode($data);
exit();
```